# How to determine I am currently processing the last touchmove event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, multi-touch, touchmove

As I determined in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176911/340947), the `touchmove` event is liable to be sent in batches depending on the combination of elements being touched.

If I have three fingers each touching a different element, but I still want to be able to process the motion of all three fingers together (for example to define an interaction on a common parent of these 3 elements), I would basically have to consolidate the data coming out of the touch events which are likely to be issued in "clumps" of three `touchmove` events for each device input sample.

While a simple workaround is to just "make one big covering element" and handle it the usual way, I intend to go after the holy grail of wrapping complex manipulations on complex DOM structures in a simple-to-deploy piece of code.

As such it is clear that I want to either use the data out of `touches` list within the last-inbound `touchmove`, or collect the contents of `changedTouches` of each `touchmove`. I have currently been writing a routine which tracks the identifiers of touches and once it sees one repeated it will know at that point that we're looking at the first `touchmove` out of the next group (the next input tick).

This is clearly sub-optimal because I have now introduced an up to 16ms delay on processing the input.

I did come up with something that could work: If the events are sent in in the order that the touch `identifiers` are in, then when I am processing the `changedTouches` list which ends with the touch corresponding to the highest-numbered `identifier` created (and I know this from the `touchstart` event), then that would be sufficient to indicate that I have received through the `touchmoves` so far all of the info for the current timestep from the hardware.

Update: What I have implemented is a variable that tracks *one* of the fingers and once it sees that finger in a `touchmove` `changedTouches`, it goes and runs a loop that processes all values in `touches`. This completely fails to provide the correct information. The one touch that it checks against might not move, and in that case no `changedTouches` is produced for it.

What other things could I do?

Comment: It appears that the `Touch`es (the elements inside the `changedTouches` and `touches` lists) are directly updated and it may be reasonable to say that once any of them change, all of them would already have been updated from the data from hardware. As I log all the `touchmove` events the `Touch` objects inside the lists all contain the same (final location) position data...

Comment: That would be the reasonable way to implement the browser: When your touch sensor provides the updated array of touch positions and IDs, fill up the `Touch` objects and then issue out the `touchmove` events. It wouldn't make any sense to set the `Touch` objects in an interleaved fashion while issuing the `touchmove`s.